# How do I re-route /register on laravel to my SPA application?

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5.7

Please help me on this one, I am building an SPA with Vue, the login page is the root page

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

// this is my HomeController index method
public function index()
{
    return view('layouts.app');
}
```

This login page loads from the usual blade file , login.blade.php, then once login is successful, it then goes to the `/home` which is handled by my `HomeController`. The controller only renders the view of the layout where Vue will then take over from there. Also, I am using the laravel-roles library from jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles, so I only want Admin to be able to register user with the same register function that comes from auth, I’ver done that, and everything works just fine, but the issue now is that, when I’m inside the SPA, If I change the url to the root like `http://127.0.0.1:8000` it goes back to the login page again, Also the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/register` also goes to the register blade file instead of the register.vue i created and routed. How can i handle this?

This is my Vue Router

```
const routes = [
  {
    name: 'Default',
    path: '/',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    name: 'Home',
    path: '/home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    name: 'Register',
    path: '/register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  } 

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload or try to go to another page manually it will go Laravel Route because you are on Laravel PORT `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. Only vue routes work on when you click a `Link` not by manually. For this issue I always try to to split Laravel and Vue.

Comment: How do you achieve this?, I mean the splitting

Comment: I have faced same problem several times.

Comment: yeah, if you could give me an idea of how to solve this issue on your own, I'll appreciate

Comment: I make API in Laravel and make app using `vue-cli`. Then call the API using `axios` or `fetch` and this is best practice for a good programmer.

Comment: Okay, this is exactly what I am doing, works fine, I am only scared if my users go through the /register manually on the browser, it goes to the blade instead

Comment: That's great :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your routes/web.php you should have  `Auth::routes()` directive. 
Get rid of it and replace it with

```
$this->get('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('admin/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

$this->get('admin/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('admin/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

$this->get('admin/password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
 $this->post('admin/password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
$this->get('admin/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
$this->post('admin/password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Now, you can get rid of the routes you don't need and replace them with whatever might seem appropriate.
I hope that helps.

Comment: why did you add admin/*  in the route?

Comment: Sorry it was a copy&paste from mine proj, feel free to adjust it accordingly